# Early 2008 Mac Pro random wake up and other oddities

Tags: macos, mac, sleep-wake

When I first purchased the machine in 2008 it ran flawlessly under Leopard.  Ever since I upgraded to later iterations of OS X, my machine would randomly wake up from sleep but it's not a full on wake as the monitors don't turn on, just the audible click sound from the Mac and a few minutes later it will go back to sleep again.  Happens 3-4 times through the night when I'm sleeping.

Secondly, when I wake it from sleep, my optical drive will no longer be available.  I have to do a full hard restart to gain that functionality again only to lose it again if my machine goes to sleep.  One last thing is when I initiate the sleep process, it takes a good 30 seconds before it actually goes idle.   Never had these issues with Leopard.

Can anyone offer insights as to how I may resolve this?

Comment: What OS is it running now?

Comment: It's running Yosemite but the problem started when I first upgraded from Leopard. According to specs I've found the computer first came with Lepoard in 2008, not Tiger as I previously stated.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the OS?

Comment: Yes I have reinstalled the OS many times but it doesn't make a difference.